# Mono for Android - OutOfMemoryError

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am having problems finding a memory leak in my Mono for Android application. I believe I am following all best practices, outlined later, but I keep getting OutOfMemoryError after a consistent, reproducible number of run-throughs of an activity.

Using `ddms` on the emulator I can see that my app is consuming around 200 extra "data objects" and about 30kB of memory every time our `ViewFlipper` flips to the next page. We are also consuming other resources, but at a much lower rate.

I use the `ViewFlipper` a little unconventionally; it only flips in one direction, and remove the `View`s that have already been shown:

```
while (flipper.ChildCount > 2)
{
    flipper.RemoveViewAt(0);
}
```

I have taken great care to `Dispose()` of any references to any `View`s we have used, as [described in this blog post](http://www.fizzylogic.nl/mono-for-android-memory-management-tips). I use `using` religiously for all UI components (which automatically `Dispose()` the object at the end of the scope):

```
using (TextView questionView = header.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.question))
{
    questionView.Text = question.Text;
}
```

This does not seem to have any effect on the memory leak. I use the same pattern whenever I load `Bitmap`s (usually PNG files, less than 20kB in size), which I do quite frequently.

*Update*: I load bitmaps using an extension method:

```
public static Bitmap BitmapFromAsset(this Context context, String asset)
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    using (Stream stream = context.Assets.Open(asset))
    {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);
        stream.Close();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

The bitmaps are then used like this:

```
using (Bitmap b = this.BitmapFromAsset(path))
{
    imageView.SetImageBitmap(b);
}
```

*Update*: As Aranda suggests below, I use delegates, so this is a common pattern in my code:

```
using (View button = FindViewById(Resource.Id.button))
{
    button.Click += delegate
    {
        // do something
    };
}
```

Changing this so that I remove the handlers when the `View` is removed makes no difference in the leaking.

*Update*: [Bug posted with Xamarin with example project](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=752).

Answer (score 1):

I had a slightly similar, and very hard to find issue (albiet on WP7, but it's still relevant as it's all .Net). Turned out I had attached some delegates to my GameScreen class from another class that didn't go out of scope. Make sure you are doing -= any attached events and delegates as well as losing the reference to the view instance.

Comment: Yes, I am using delegate to attach to the different `View`s. So I have to remove all event handlers that are using delegates, or all event handlers in general? Say you have this: `using (Button b = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button)) { b.Click += delegate (object s, EventArgs e) { /* code */ }; }`, where would you remove the delegate?

Comment: Even when removing the `Click` handlers from the equation, I am still leaking memory in the same way as described above.

Comment: Interesting. Your particular example there wouldn't cause it to leak because the delegate is an anonymous method, and would be in the scope of the view instance itself. I think I didn't explain myself well either. Mine was leaking because my GameScreen had attached one of it's methods to an event (or delegate) in my Engine class. The Engine was still holding a reference to the GameScreen class via the attached event. Not necessarily anything to do with your leak though :(

Comment: Anonymous delegates are still (compiler-generated) methods. `o.E += (sender, e) => ...` is no different than `o.E += MethodName;` and the former can still keep `o` alive just like the latter can.

Comment: Good point jonp. I was also wrong in that the delegate would not (in this case) be in the scope of the Button view. @Vegard, did you have any luck finding the leak? Perhaps you need to explicitly Dispose the bitmaps after the view goes out of scope? I know you have them in `using` blocks, but perhaps the imageViews themselves take a copy that needs disposing?