# Mono for Android Memory Leaks

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, xamarin.android

Im having problems with the Garbage Collector in Mono for Android and i was researching about it and the say that i have to put manually GC.Collect() in every OnDestroy() methods in order to release objects that im not using, Also im trying to use Dispose for Java.Lang.Objects, but the App is still cosuming and incrementing memory. How can i solve it?

Comment: Can you provide more info about your research?

Comment: I can provide some links which im refering to the same problem

Comment: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection#Helping_the_GC

Comment: http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Memory-Leak-with-Background-Image-td5165833.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331417/mono-for-android-outofmemoryerror

Answer (score 6):

The primary question: is it an actual problem? Garbage collectors are, by nature, non-deterministic, so memory use will vary quite a bit. This isn't necessarily a problem; it's just part of how things are. If you're regularly running out of global references or exhausting the process heap, then this is a problem. If you're just seeing grefs increase but they decrease when a collection naturally occurs, it might not be worth worrying about.

If it is a problem, we need specifics about what the problem is. For example, [Bitmap](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.Graphics.Bitmap) instances can easily [exhaust memory](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monodroid/2012-April/009704.html), and [solutions for Bitmaps](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monodroid/2012-April/009730.html) are not necessarily applicable to everything in general.

To get more information, you can enable [Global Reference Messages](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Global_Reference_Messages) to see when global references are created and destroyed.

Furthermore, we're constantly updating the GC heuristics. Mono for Android 4.1.0 introduced a change in which `GC.Collet()` is called automatically once we hit a gref threshold of 80% of the maximum gref value for the platform (1800 grefs on the emulator). This should remove much of the need for `OnDestroy()` to call `GC.Collect()`, though (as always) the GC may kick in at "inopportune moments," so an explicit `GC.Collect()` may be preferable anyway.